# MYSQL command to execute multiple .sql files

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am wanting to write and execute a single mysql .sql file that will execute multiple other .sql files. I am looking for something equivalent to Oracle's:

```
@script1.sql
@script2.sql
@script3.sql
```

Does MYSQL have a command?

Answer (score 11):

From bash or any shell, you can run as follows

```
cat script*.sql | mysql -u root -pYOURPASSWORD  dbname
```

This would execute all for your sql files for 'dbname'

Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

```
source script1.sql;
source script2.sql;
...
```

Comment: I've actually tried that before, but no success. I am getting the error: 

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source user.sql' at line 1`. 

I have a build.sql file that I want to execute from within Eclipse that runs multiple files. Does the command you wrote have to be ran from a mysql prompt?